# How does one dismantle the ThinkPad Mini Dock Series 3 (model 4337)?

Tags: hardware-failure, thinkpad, docking-station

I have a ThinkPad Mini Dock Series 3 with a spring that is too stiff, causing problems with the connectivity when a computer is docked. I tried to open it so that I can soften the spring, but hit a brick wall.

I removed all the screws I could find at the the bottom and the back panel of the docking station, but the bottom part of the plastic case would still not part from the top of the plastic case. I even looked under some of the various stickers for more screws, but found nothing. Can anyone please help with pointers on dismantling this docking station?

Comment: there might be clips as well. You might want to very carefully pry it apart at the seams preferably with a [spudger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spudger)

Comment: post an answer and select it yourself - there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fair answer found. [This not-very-good video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Feev_4DzfVI) shows how one enables a Mini Dock Series 3 docking station to be compatible with the ThinkPad Tablet models. Amongst other things, it mentions the screws at the top as well, under the "docking cover" (the plastic plate that depresses whenever a computer is docked). Also, it seems that in order to reach the springs, there is no need to dismantle the docking station but only to remove that said "docking cover" at the top.